# Cache data at server level

Tags: c#, iis-7

Is it possible to Cache the data at IIS level?, I just want to minimize number of requests to my DB where data will not change frequently. And All the users will see the same data.

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: What do you mean by IIS level? Cached by IIS and not your code?

Comment: yes ,some data which is common and won't change freqently.  I don't want cache at client web page, I want cache at IIS server..

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30165/An-Easy-Way-to-Cache-Static-Data-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the [`HttpContext.Current.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) (or one of the other ways available to reference the same thing).

There are also other configurable properties within IIS itself to set how to manage caching and serving of particular file types and what not, compression etc. depending on what context you mean by "caching server side".

Comment: Hi Grant, Thanks for your reply... I am a beginner in asp.net and IIS  if you have any example please provide me.. My senario , application will make asnc call to retrieve data object from the DB and placing them in the webpage.. I want to read the dataobject from server cache  if available.